# GAC query regarding slow initial load for an asp.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, gac

I have a single-tenant ASP.NET web application which is deployed on a Windows 2008R2 web server and DB is on another server.

My application uses at-least 20 3rd party DLLs, and the total size of these DLLs is around 150MB. Assuming we have 20 customer sites running in IIS, these 20+ DLLs hog a lot of memory space as they get loaded in each individual IIS process. My problems:

Very slow site load times: a fresh customer single-tenant install takes around 3-5 min to load the home page. I am assuming it takes that much time to load all these DLLs in memory space.

RAM hogging: My RAM is being used up like crazy, as we scale (get more customer installs), precious memory space will get used up for these same DLLs. These 3rd party DLLs will not change much in future (no upgrades).

So given these conditions, should I go ahead and install these assemblies in GAC? From what I read, I find developers advising me against GAC for various reasons (which I do understand), but I still feel that given my conditions, installing these assemblies in GAC will not only improve my load times significantly, but also save precious RAM.

Any inputs would be great.

Note that I have already profiled the application performance using ANTS and dotTrace, and there are no significant bottlenecks which would cause the app to load so slow during the first hit. Also note that application performance is acceptable AFTER the first hit. It loads all pages within 3 seconds, but the first hit takes 3-5 min.

Comment: Slow first loads are expected on dynamically compiled websites.  If you wish to share DLLS among instances, yes, strong-name them and stick them in the gac.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you load the assemblies from GAC, the memory footprint would be same because each application will load its own copy of the DLLs in its own memory space.

I would recommend starting an initial hit to your site as a background process meanwhile showing the customer some important or useful info in the foreground so that user experience is not hampered in the first hit.